# regular expression to validate if string only contains letter and digit and has maximum length

Tags: regex

When I have this expression `^\d{3}$` then if I input `123` then it will return as `1 match`. But, if I input `1234` then it will return to me `no match` which is good.

Now, I have this other expression

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,5}
```

But I test this on https://regexr.com/ and I don't see it works the way I expected.

If I enter `helloworld` as an input example I am not expecting it to pick up any match but in this case it says `1 match` and it is highlighting the word `hello`. How can I modify the expression so that this input will return me 'no match'

Thanks

Comment: You're missing the `$` at the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add the last `$` if you want match exactly

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,5}$
```

`^` ==> start wtih

`[0-9a-zA-Z]` ==> list of characters

`{1,5}` ==> occurences between 1 to 5

`$` ==> finish by

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a $ at the end of the the characters you want to match. The `^` and `$` asserts that the 1,2,3,4 or 5 characters also contains the beginning and end of the match.

`^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,5}$`